# Git pull does not pull .gitignore

Tags: linux, git, virtual-machine

I am using Google VM(linux) to run some codes in my git repository. I manually added a .gitignore file in my repository via web, and then tried to perform "git pull" in my VM. However even though git status shows my branch is up-to-date, the newly added .gitignore file is not pulled or cannot be seen in my VM. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you added and committed `.gitignore` on the branch and pushed to the remote repository?

Comment: I believe so. I manually added the file via the github website, and when I saved the file there was an explicit "commit changes" button.

Comment: Try `ls -la`, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are doing wrong is using plain `ls`. `.gitignore` is a hidden file. Try with `ls -a` and it should show up.